# Angular Router - Lazy loaded module can't match URL with a param

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I previously had the following working code, back when my entire app was eagerly loaded

```js
// previous code
const homeRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
    { path: 'user/:userId', component: ProfileComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    // others not shown
  ]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

The `/profile` page is the same component as the `/user/{id}` page - but with a slightly different layout, so I treat them slightly different.

I have since upgraded from Angular 7 to Angular 8, and implemented Lazy Loading, which works everywhere in my app except here. I assume this is because this route unlike the others has a param?

Here is my new **routing code**:

```js
const homeRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    { path: 'user/:id', loadChildren: () => import('../profile/profile.module').then(mod => mod.ProfileModule) },
    { path: 'profile', loadChildren: () => import('../profile/profile.module').then(mod => mod.ProfileModule) },
    // others not shown
  ]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

The **profile module** has the following code:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: ProfileComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProfileComponent, // others not shown
  ],
  entryComponents: [] // contents not shown
})
export class ProfileModule { }
```

The problem is when I try to navigate to `/user/5cd466b3cdd9b31594bad5d7` I get the following error:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user/5cd466b3cdd9b31594bad5d7'`

What's going on here?

EDIT: I made the profile component non-lazy loaded (and removed it from its module, putting it in the previous location - the home module). I also made one of the components that routes to it non-lazy loaded (and removed it from its module, putting it in the previous location - the home module). Then it worked. When I made the component that links to the profile lazy-loaded once more, it stopped working. So it appears that calling this.router.navigate() from inside a component that is lazy loaded causes problems. I don't know why, though.

Comment: can't you move the id route as a child to user ?

Comment: So essentially something like adding an additional route inside of the profile module like this: `{ path: ':id', component: ProfileComponent },` (and removing `:id` from the home routing module)? I've tried that, and it fails with the same error.

Comment: okay 
I have a question regarding the way you have structured, 2 paths are pointing to same module, so have you tried using redirectTo? When you say they are slightly different, what does that mean as they are pointing to the exact same component

Comment: Same component, but I apply slightly different logic (hide a few buttons, etc.) based on whether the ID parameter is specified or not.

Comment: Redirect to would be difficult to use here because the ID isn't known in the case of the `/profile` route.

Comment: can you provide stackblitz example having a similar issue?

Comment: Working on it, allow me a few moments.

Comment: It is not, no. It's a weird convention but I'm working on fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem is that you are lazy loading the profile module two times in your HomeRoutingModule. Try implementing this like this:

**HomeRoutingModule:**

```js
const homeRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    { path: 'user', 
      loadChildren: () => import('../profile/profile.module').then(mod => mod.ProfileModule) },
    // others not shown
  ]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(homeRoutes)], // use forRoot if it's your root module
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

**ProfileModule:**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: ':id', component: ProfileComponent },
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProfileComponent, // others not shown
  ],
  entryComponents: [] // contents not shown
})
export class ProfileModule { }
```

You need to change your links from 'profile' to 'user/profile'.

I don't know if this resolve your problem, but even if it does not, it is a cleaner implementation.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but during my own testing I suspected the same problem, so I tried deleting the reference to the module that _didn't_ have a parameter, and I still had the same issue.

Comment: Can confirm - this did not fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to access a **route with parameters** from a **lazy loaded module** you'll have to define the route patterns in the **parent** module and in the **lazy-loaded module**.

So, your code becomes:

```js
const homeRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    // Declaring this is IMPORTANT!
    { path: 'user', loadChildren: () => import('../user/user.module').then(mod => mod.UserModule) },
    { path: 'user/:id', loadChildren: () => import('../user/user.module').then(mod => mod.UserModule) },
    { path: 'profile', loadChildren: () => import('../profile/profile.module').then(mod => mod.ProfileModule) },
    // others not shown
  ]
}];
```

then, in your **user-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
   /* ... */
  { path: ':id', component: UserComponent },
 /* ... */
];
```

[Here is a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkuufr?file=src%2Fapp%2Findividual%2Findividual.module.ts) that applies the aforementioned ideas.

Comment: I'll try this and see if that helps

Comment: This does not appear to fix the problem - I do notice this error in the console of the broswer, though: `
Router Event: NavigationCancel


NavigationCancel(id: 1, url: '/user/5cca1738d578271ff895691c')
vendor.js (177715,13)



[object Object]: {id: 1, reason: "Navigation ID 1 is not equal to the current navigation id 2", url: "/user/5cca1738d578271ff895691c"}`

Comment: Hm.. do you have a stackblitz demo? I might be missing something.

Comment: I'm trying to put one together but it's taking some time.

Comment: I still don't have one, but I have made some interesting discoveries.

Comment: Could you add them in your post?

Comment: I made the profile component non-lazy loaded (and removed it from its module, putting it in the previous location - the home module). I also made one of the components that routes to it non-lazy loaded (and removed it from its module, putting it in the previous location - the home module). Then it worked. When I made the component that links to the profile lazy-loaded once more, it stopped working. So it appears that calling `this.router.navigate(['user', id])` from inside a component that is lazy loaded causes problems. I don't know why, though.

Comment: I've been reading the routing section on the Angular docs and I can't find any reason why this is happening.

Comment: I’ll check it once again tomorrow. Have you tried those things? : in your profile module, define a route with `{path: ‘id’ }` and in the parent module, make the ‘profile route” to be defined first.

Comment: As I said - I removed the profile from a module entirely and moved it back into the home module (it worked when it lived there in the past, before lazy loading.) The problem is that when I call `this.router.navigate['user', id]) from inside of a lazy loaded module, it throws the error. If I make the same exact module non-lazy loaded (and not in its own module) then the same code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue trying to get a value from the url in this way: `localhost:4002/#/ext/assessment/4rhesksfjejw`, which the last part is the token variable I wanted to fetch. So, it was indeed the lazy loading preventing me to fetch it and the only way to access it was to transform it into a query param: `localhost:4002/#/ext/assessment?t=4rhesksfjejw` and then get it in the following way:

```
ngOnInit():{
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe({
    next: params =>{
      this._token = params["t"];
    }
  })
}
```